# Vim - mysqli functions with phpcomplete

Tags: php, mysql, vim, mysqli

I installed [phpcomplete.vim](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim) with Vundle hoping that I would get autocomplete for PHP.

However only a few mysqli functions appear. Not even mysqli_connect() shows up.

Have I done something wrong or these functions are not implemented? Can I get them with other plugins or something?

Comment: Just found this in the README: `Built-in functions, classes, interfaces and constatns are grouped together by the extension. Only the enabled extensions will be loaded for the plugin, the defaultly enabled ones can be found in.`. Is the mysqli extension enabled?

Comment: You mean this `let g:phpcomplete_add_function_extensions = ["mysqli"]` ? I've made this but the results are the same as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the built-in function/class [maps](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim/ee2b5d557f3b3f17d54e7a891121a7a828628f84/misc/builtin.vim) (caution, it's a pretty big file) does not contain the every `mysqli_*` function, like the [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) (some functions are there like `mysqli_get_cache_stats`).

The root cause is probably [due to the code](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim/blob/915c4fd5645bafe1bdb7b9a755fb30e5fbd2c0c7/bin/generator/classes.php) which generates these maps from the docs and in this case it's probably a bug / lack of support for these kind of aliases (like `mysqli_connect`) and functions those can be called both procedural and via the various mysqli related classes (like [`mysqli_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)).

If you are using a github master version of the plugin you can add entries manually via the [`misc/builtin_manual.vim`](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim/blob/318697f05ea2945ba461eeaf545913e1e17f8df4/misc/builtin_manual.vim) file, it would look something like this (just add it to the end of the file):

```
call extend(g:phpcomplete_builtin['functions']['mysqli'], {
\ 'mysqli_connect(': '[ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] | mysqli',
\ 'mysqli_escape_string(': 'string $escapestr | string',
\ 'mysqli_execute(': ' mysqli_stmt $stmt | bool',
\ 'mysqli_set_opt(': ' mysqli $link, int $option, mixed $value | bool',
\ })
```

Just add more of these you'd like to see in the results.

If you want to play around with the built-in maps (they've not been updated in 10 months when i write this) you can find the generator in [here](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim/blob/915c4fd5645bafe1bdb7b9a755fb30e5fbd2c0c7/bin/generate_builtin_dicts.php), you'll need the docs from [php.net](http://php.net/download-docs.php) and command line php.

I'd really appreciate if you could open an [issue](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim/issues) on github, so we can have a proper place for discussion and such.

### Update:

I've [pushed a commit](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim/commit/63981b8c1c45b64902f79cabd3df2c190d8d23f0) with updated built-in maps and support for the "Procedural style" aliases in the generator.

Comment: Thanks! I won't be able to test it for a few days but I'll check it as soon as I can

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This post discusses the version of phpcomplete.vim that comes with Vim 7.4. The version the in question is shawncplus' version: [phpcomplete.vim](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim). I would highly recommend upgrading to use shawncplus version as it is much more complete (pun!).

#### Old phpcomplete.vim

Sadly php complete that ships with Vim does not have many common functions, e.g. `json_decode`. I have added the completion entries myself.

Add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`:

```
if !exists('g:php_builtin_functions')
  call phpcomplete#LoadData()
  let g:php_builtin_functions['json_decode('] = 'string $json [, bool $assoc [, int $depth [, int $options]]] | mixed'
  let g:php_builtin_functions['json_encode('] = 'mixed $value [, int $options [, int $depth]] | string'
  let g:php_builtin_functions['json_last_error_msg('] = 'void | string'
  let g:php_builtin_functions['json_last_error('] = 'void | int'
endif
```

Note: my example just adds the JSON functions. You will need to change these for your mysqli functions.

As a bonus here is my version of the `K` command I use for php files (Put in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`):

```
function! s:PHPQuickMan(word)
  let word = a:word . '('
  echo word . get(g:php_builtin_functions, word, ' can not be found')
endfunction

nnoremap <buffer> K :call <SID>PHPQuickMan(expand('<cword>'))<cr>
```

Comment: You could fork the repository, add your changes and make a pull request. No need for every user to add this again.